# A warning is shown when Optional.isPresent and Optional.get are called "on different" levels?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-8, option-type

In the following code snippet, I have `Foo` class with a method that always returns the same instance of `Optional`. And then I have another `OneMoreClass` class that uses `Foo` class.

You can see from the source code that it's safe to call `get()` method in `method1` because it is always checked in the `method2`.

The problem that IntelliJ IDEA still shows a warning (you can just copy this snippet to IDEA and you will see the issue).

```
public class Example {

    public static class Foo {

        private final Optional<String> value = Optional.empty();

        public Optional<String> bar() {
            return value;
        }
    }

    public static class OneMoreClass {
        void method1(final Foo foo) {
            method2(foo);
            System.out.println(foo.bar().get()); // here the warning is shown in IntelliJ IDEA: 
                                                 // "Optional.get()" without "isPresent()" check
        }

        void method2(final Foo foo) {
            if (!foo.bar().isPresent()) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("No value");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**The question is:** how can I fix the warning? Is there any trick to avoid this warning?

Comment: How should IntelliJ be sure `foo.bar()` always returns the same instance?

Comment: @JohannesKuhn well, it can look at the code :) It seems this check is not so smart. But I'm surely not the first person who faces this issue.

Comment: @RomanProshin what if a subclass has overridden `method2(Foo)`? What if `Foo` has a subclass whose `bar()` method does not return the same `Optional` every time? Is IntelliJ supposed to know at compile time any subclass that could potentially exist at runtime?

Comment: @Holger yes, I agree that in some circumstances IDEA won't be able to handle the code, but it should be able to handle this specific example

Comment: Why? There is nothing in these classes preventing the existence of such subclasses. Even if they do not exist now, creating classes with overridable methods forms a contract that allows them in principle. Even if you take measures to prevent such subclasses, the entire scenario is so far away from real life cases, that it’s not clear why IDE developers shall waste their time to add special support for it into the code audit.

Comment: What if a subclass overrides `method2` to behave differently?

Comment: @OleV.V. yes, you're right, but even if the class is marked as `final`, intellij idea seems doesn't detect the case as Tagir explained in his answer (and I've also checked such a snippet)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Disclosure*: I'm an IntelliJ IDEA developer, responsible for this feature.

---

Technically, it's possible to cause `get()` failing using your code like this:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Example.OneMoreClass().method1(new Example.Foo() {
        int x;

        @Override
        public Optional<String> bar() {
            return x++ % 2 == 0 ? Optional.of("foo") : Optional.empty();
        }
    });
}
```

As your `Foo` class and `bar()` method are not final, IDEA cannot be sure that they are stable. However, IDEA still warns even if you declare `Foo` as final. We actually trust that `bar()` result could be stable, to avoid noise warnings. The main problem is that an `isPresent()` check is moved into the separate method and our inter-procedural analysis is not that smart. Current analyzer implementation does only a few things when an unknown user method is called:

1. We infer result nullability, result mutability (in very limited sense), method purity and [contracts](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/contract-annotations.html) like `@Contract("null -> false")` looking into method implementation. This analysis is pretty limited and applied to non-overridable methods only, so it doesn't apply here. Even if we declare `method2` as final, this analysis yields nothing.
2. We infer not-null parameters, looking into method implementation. This works in your case: if you call `method2(null)`, you will get a warning. Of course, it's not helpful to solve your problem.
3. In some cases, we inline very small and simple stable methods. This works only if method to be inlined is stable, has no arguments, called on the same class, has single return statement and doesn't call any other methods (probably there are more restrictions). It helps in the cases like this:

```java
    public static final class OneMoreClass {
        @Nullable String foo;

        void test() {
            if (isValid()) {
                System.out.println(foo.trim()); // no possible NPE warning
            }
        }

        boolean isValid() {
            return foo != null;
        }
    }
```

None of these approaches covers your case. We occasionally improve the analysis making it smarter, but we are pretty limited in CPU resources. Don't forget that we analyse the code online, and the code is constantly edited invalidating the previous analysis results. Deep interprocedural analysis requires much more CPU time and we don't like making the IDEA significantly slower.

I must say that your code might confuse readers as well. I think that your sample is the simplified version of bigger code, and the reader might be not sure whether the optional is actually always present at given point of code. There's a good old mechanism to assist code readers as well as protect yourself against accidental mistakes (what if somebody modifies method2 later removing the `isPresent()` check without proper adaptation of call sites?). That mechanism is called assertions. So **the answer**: add an assert, and the code would be more clear both for IDE, and for readers:

```java
    void method1(final Foo foo) {
        method2(foo);
        assert foo.bar().isPresent();
        System.out.println(foo.bar().get()); // the warning is gone
    }
```

Comment: I have this same error if I add a JUnit assert instead. For example: 
assertThat("Should be present", foo.bar().isPresent());
assertThat("Property should be Something", foo.bar().getProperty(), is("Something"));

Is there any workaround for this? I didn't want to use if-else condition in this case.

Comment: @FelipeMosso this should work with JUnit asserts. Please file a [YouTrack issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/) providing the complete code sample.

Comment: I have just created the ticket with a sample code. Thanks! https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-260003

Answer (score 2):

You're not going to be able to get rid of the warning in this instance.  The code inspection that generates warning is not robust enough to completely analyze all code paths and understand the intent behind `method2`.

You could do something like this, though, to achieve the same result:

```
 void method1(final Foo foo) {
    String bar = getBar(foo);
    System.out.println(bar);
}

String getBar(final Foo foo) {
    return foo.bar().orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("No value"));
}
```

Though honestly, now that I've been reminded of the `.orElseThrow` method, it's probably easier to simplify this to just:

```
void method1(final Foo foo) {
    String bar = foo.bar().orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("No value"));
    System.out.println(bar);
}
```

---

You can also genericize some of the functionality. It doesn't buy you much in this case, but if there's a lot more code that you want to run that is triggered by the optional being empty, it might make sense.  IntelliJ will give a warning here, too, which you can suppress:

```
@SuppressWarnings("OptionalUsedAsFieldOrParameterType")
<T> T unwrapOrThrow(Optional<T> optional) {
    return optional.orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("No value"));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately, it's still not the best solution, but a "crutch". I was thinking about some general solution based on OOP: like producing a new instance of a class that doesn't have any `Optional`... but couldn't find a clear solution. That's why I'm here now :)

Comment: This is the way to go. Notice, though, that `getBar` (or `unwrapOrThrow`) should probalby just call `Optional.orElseThrow()`)

Comment: You could certainly convert your object to a different class with no optionals, but it'll be an entirely manual process.  It might be worth taking a step back and examining why you're using optionals in the first place.  Their intent is to enforce null-checks on whatever code calls the method that returns the Optional.  The real power is when you're writing your own libraries, because you can say, "This method might return a null, and now you *have* to handle that."  But if this is all internal to your code, it might be simpler and cleaner to just have traditional null checks.

Comment: @OhleC Good call.  I completely forgot about that.  I'll edit my answer to take that into account.

Answer (score 0):

Optional is the mean to avoid NPE. If you check Optional.get() you'll see this method throws exception if Optional.isPresent() false. So no any benefits if you using "get" without preliminary check "isPresent". To fix it check "isPresent" before "get". But I would suggest consider something like "getOrElse", "ifPresent" etc.

Comment: Yeah, I agree: `get()` can only be called after `isPresent()`, but this is exactly the case in my snippet - but those methods are called in different methods. And IntelliJ IDEA doesn't see that.

Comment: Of course IDE cannot recognize this situation. It's too complex for it. It's not Java issue, it's not compilation issue. It's best practice stuff. And probably this is not IDE warning but Sonar one. Generally the approach when you need to use "isPresent" and "get" is not good approach and is being considered as a bad practice. I would use this one in your case: foo.bar().ifPresent(System.out::println)